# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type from an rvalue of type for arma::subvec

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, armadillo

The vector `y_long_name` has 100 members and I plan to manipulate only a subvector of it made of first three members. The `subvector` function is used in my code like a left value:

```
y_long_name.subvec(0,2)=A*x1;
```

However C++ does not recognize it as a left value. How can I define `yr` to be used instead of `y_long_name.subvec(0,2)`?

what I want to do is to use the short form `yr` instead of `y_long_name.subvec(0,2)` but without using macro.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

int main()
{
    const arma::vec::fixed<3> x1={1.2,3.5,-0.27};   
    arma::mat::fixed<3,3> A={{5,3,6},{8,2,11},{7,5,9}};

    arma::vec::fixed<3> y1=A*x1; // ok

    arma::vec::fixed<100> y_long_name;
    y_long_name.subvec(0,2)=A*x1; // ok

    arma::vec::fixed<3>& yr=y_long_name.subvec(0,2);
    yr=A*x1;

    y_long_name.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:14:48: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘arma::Col<double>::fixed<3ull>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘arma::subview_col<double>’
  arma::vec::fixed<3>& yr=y_long_name.subvec(0,2)
```

Comment: Try `auto&& yr = long_name.subvec(0,2);`

Comment: @M.M, thanks a lot. That works perfectly. please leave it as an answer.

Comment: @M.M Have any weblog to follow?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to avoid the use of [subviews](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat) while still accessing subviews. This is generally not advised. However, there is an *unsafe* way to accomplish this by using vector constructors that take pointers to [external memory](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_col). For example:

```
vec a(10, fill::zeros);

double* a_data = a.memptr();

vec b( &a_data[5], 2, false, true );  // create 'b from part of vector 'a'

b(0) = 123.0;  // changing elements in vector 'b' will also change 'a'

a.print("a:");
```

Note that the above operation is *unsafe*, as the memory allocated for use by 'a' could be freed and reallocated by any operation applied to 'a'.  Vector 'b' would then be using a pointer to invalid memory. In other words, use the above trick only if you really know what you are doing.

Comment: what I want to do is to use the short form `yr` instead of `y_long_name.subvec(0,2)` but without using macro.

Comment: using `y_long_name.subvec(0,2)` is much neater than using pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`subvec` doesn't return a `vec`; it turns a view into the original vector, which can be converted to a temporary `vec` - which you can't bind a non-const reference to.

So you're forcing the wrong type for `yr`, which is causing the problem. Better to not specify it at all and just use the type that `subvec` gives you:

```
auto & yr = y_long_name.subvec(0,2);
```

Or, since you don't actually need a reference:

```
auto yr = y_long_name.subvec(0,2);
```

Comment: `auto & yr = ...` gives a similar error. 

`auto yr = ...` compiles ok. but changing `yr` is not reflected to the `y_long_name` vector.